# Ошибка при попытке оплаты pyQiwip2p и pyTelegrmBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

```
    if c.data == 'order':
        bill = str(c.data[6:])
        if str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == 'PAID':
                db.sub(1, c.message.chat.id)
                bot.send_message(c.chat.id, 'Вы успешно купили подписку! Скоро с вами свяжется администратор')
        elif str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == 'WAITING':
                bot.send_message(c.chat.id, 'Счет не оплачен, попробуйте снова')
        elif str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == 'REJECTED':
                bot.send_message(c.chat.id, 'Счет не оплачен, попробуйте снова')
        elif str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == 'EXPIRED':
                bot.send_message(c.chat.id, 'Счет не оплачен, попробуйте снова')
```

> Возникает ошибка ValueError: Code: 404. Qiwi response is not JSON. This is Qiwi-side bug. Please try again later or check response. Qiwi response saved to QiwiCrash_1674075638.txt. P.S. The number of requests per minute may have been exceeded. You can wait, change auth_key or cry.

Comment: Возникает ошибка ValueError: Code: 404. Qiwi response is not JSON. This is Qiwi-side bug. Please try again later or check response. Qiwi response saved to QiwiCrash_1674075638.txt. P.S. The number of requests per minute may have been exceeded. You can wait, change auth_key or cry.

Comment: А ошибку перевести?

Comment: Ошибку переводил, понял в чем ошибка но не нашел где

Answer (score 0):

это сообщение об ошибке, которое говорит о том, что сервер `Qiwi` не смог обработать запрос и возвращает:

> статус 404 (Not Found)

Это может быть связано с несколькими причинами:

- Неверно сформированный запрос
- Неверный `auth_key`
- Превышен лимит запросов в минуту
- Нужно проверить корректность запроса и `auth_key`, а также подождать некоторое время, если действительно превышен лимит запросов.

Comment: Я понял, не подскажите где у меня ошибка в коде?